# Webpack output all the files within a directory with the same name into a different folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I have the following directory:

```
  - src/
    - js/
      - profile1/
        - script1.js
        - script2.js
      - profile2/
        - script3.js
        - script4.js
      - script5.js
  - dist/
    - js/
  package.js
  webpack.config.js
```

I am trying to webpack all JS files from `/src/js` into `dist/js` folder conserving the same naming and folder structure.

I could write a different config for each file and webpack each JS file, but I am wondering if there is a set of config that I can write to do all the operations in one shot.

I have tried:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/js/*.js',
  output: {
    filename: '*.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  }
}
```

failed miserably.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can match the entry file first like using [glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob) (install it with `npm i glob`). Then you can change the output dynamically by appending `[name]` to `output.filename`. Here's the complete code:

```
const path = require('path');
const glob = require('glob');

module.exports = {
  entry: Object.fromEntries(glob.sync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js/**/*.js')).map((v) => [
    v.split('src/js/')[1], v,
  ])),
  output: {
    filename: '[name]',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/js'),
  },
};
```

Comment: ok, I tried, it worked for files in src/js folder. I also have subfolders in side src/js. Can I run it recursively to webpack not only the files in src/js, but all the files in the subfolders as well?

Comment: Yes, you can try replacing `src/js/*.js` with `src/js/**/*.js`.

Comment: Hi @Yusuf T, I tried again. But it just throws every JS file inside the `dist` folder without any folder structure. Is it possible make the build to respect the existing folder structure? My current output options are  ```output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },```

Comment: Thank you very much. Even ChatGPT 4 could not help me with this. I thought the issue was in "output" but the input given in "entry" depends on the structure